# Django Rest Framework fields source validation naming issues

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to ensure DRF serializer attribute or validated_data parameter for validate and create method does not change to model attribute name when field name are declare in different name using [source argument](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    new_name = HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        source='old_name',
        view_name='viewset-detail',
        queryset=SomeModel.objects.all(),
    )

    # override validate method
    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs['old_name'] # this is valid
        attrs['new_name'] # KeyError

    # override create method
    # problem same for create here
    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['old_name'] # this is valid
        validated_data['new_name'] # KeyError
```

Just want to know is this part of DRF design for **deserialize**(any reason) or I did this wrongly, is kind of confuse other team members when this happened

Comment: This is the expected behavior in DRF as the ***`new_name`*** is used for ***serialization*** and ***`old_name`*** is used for ***deserialization***

Comment: @ArakkalAbu ah, I thought so, thanks for the confirmation